# Windows 7 switching power settings from high performance to balanced?

Tags: windows-7

I have this weird problem with win 7 ultimate.

My computer, for some reason, sometimes decides that it's time to switch from high performance to balanced.

The computer is a self-assembled one.

Is there any way to stop this?

Answer (score 1):

Some Microsoft hotfixes/security-patches seem to have this as side-effect. (And it also happens on Windows 8 en 10.)

It started happening, as far as I can recall, in late 2015 or early 2016. Windows Update pushes some patches and suddenly the power-profile is back to balanced, regardless of what was it set to before.
They also redefined those profiles around that time. What they call "balanced" now looks more like the old "maximum power-save" profile and the "maximum power-save" profile got throttled down even further.

Really obnoxious, but easy to fix: Simply re-configure the Balanced Profile to the same settings as the High-Performance profile. As far as I know Microsoft doens't go as far as resetting the profile contents.

Comment: Did that. Hopefully it works. Will select this in a few days to make sure it really works. Thanks